# Why is VS2010 looking for framework source code when Just My Code is enabled?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

Googling this yields lots of entries on HOW TO step through Framework code. I'm trying to find out how NOT TO step into.

First check: Yes, "Enable Just My Code" is checked in the Tools->Options->Debugging.  That is supposed to keep VS2010 from looking for source code when you are stepping through a framework function (or anything else that you don't have the source to, as I understand it.)

It's not.  I'm trying to step through my code, using F11, and, if I get careless and don't switch to F10 (to step over a function call) when I get to a function that is in a library, then it throws up a dialog asking where the source for that call is, and when I cancel out of it (since I don't have the source), it aborts my Debug, and I have to start all over.

How can I avoid this behavior. As I understand the documentation, this is NOT the way it is supposed to work.  And where do we go for support when it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simply not loading symbols for the framework.

In the Symbols window, there is an option for "Automatically symbols for:" depending on the option you choose you can explicitly exclude those modules, or only specify your own modules.

I assume you are using the All modules, unless excluded option, so you should exclude the framework modules.

If you actually own the framework you can also add a StepThrough attribute to any framework functions you want to step through. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx.